# Change cursor blinking status upon state change of evil-mode

Tags: evil, hooks, cursor

I'm using evil-mode.
My goal is to have a blinking cursor upon entering evil-insert-state, and to have a non-blinking cursor in evil-normal-state.
I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
  (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook
                        (lambda () (setq blink-cursor-mode t)))
  (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook
                        (lambda () (setq blink-cursor-mode nil)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `(blink-cursor-mode 1)` to enable Blink Cursor instead.

from `(describe-variable 'blink-cursor-mode)` :

> Setting this variable directly does not take effect; either customize it (see the info node ‘Easy Customization’) or call the function ‘blink-cursor-mode’.